# quasi-poisson / Neg.Bin / Chi-square for analysing annual count data?

Tags: chi-squared-test, poisson-distribution, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, geometric-mean

I'm interested in looking at annual trends. The numbers represent the total number of a particular animal species that have been counted in that year. We see a decreasing trend, and I would like to check if the decreasing trend is statistically significant.

```
mydf <- data.frame(
Year = 2016:2020,
Count = c(21,36,26,13,5)
)
```

My first approach was to use a quasi-poisson model and a negative binomial model.

```
library(MASS) #For the neg.bin models
qp.mydf <- glm(data = mydf, formula = Count ~ Year, family = quasipoisson(link="log"))
nb.mydf <- glm.nb(data = mydf, formula = Count ~ Year)
```

While they both work, I am not sure if they are appropriate to use given the few data points I have. Alternatively, I could also do a chi-square test to check for significant changes between the years. It would also make more sense to me, because I basically only have five data points.

Because the results differ quite a bit depending on the statistical approach, I was wondering if someone could help me with deciding what method works best for the data I have.

Comment: I might use a permutation test for this (calculate something like the geometric mean decrease for the data; scramble the data order 1000 times, each time calculating the geometric mean decrease; see where your observed statistic falls in the distribution)

Comment: Thanks, I did not consider the geometric mean. Just to clarify, would you suggest that for the difference between the first and the last year (e.g. between 2016 and 2020), or the annual decrease?

Comment: I would say `mean(diff(log(Count)))` (this is the log of the geom mean, i.e. "annual decrease" of your two options)